# Vaadin 14 Polymer element this.dispatchEvent is not a function

Tags: polymer, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm trying to write a Polymer Wrapper on top of leaflet and leaflet-draw. I've managed to create the map and the drawing toolbar but I'm unable to send events to the server using the dispatchEvent method as I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.dispatchEvent is not a function`.
My class looks like this:

```
import { html, PolymerElement } from "@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
import { ThemableMixin } from "@vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/vaadin-themable-mixin.js";
import * as L from "leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js";
import * as LDraw from "leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js";
import { LeafletTypeConverter } from "./leaflet-type-converter.js";

class LeafletMap extends ThemableMixin(PolymerElement) {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <div
        id="map"
        style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      ></div>
    `;
  }

  static get is() {
    return "leaflet-map";
  }

ready() {
    super.ready();
    console.info("LeafletMap - ready() leaflet map is ready.");
    console.log("LeafletMap - ready() mapOptions: {}", this.mapOptions);

    this.leafletConverter = new LeafletTypeConverter();
    console.log("LeafletMap - ready() using converter", this.leafletConverter);

    // init leaflet map
    let map = this.toLeafletMap(this.mapOptions);
    console.log('going to add draw items');
    
    try {
        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
         map.addLayer(drawnItems);
         var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
             edit: {
                 featureGroup: drawnItems
             }
         });
        map.addControl(drawControl);
        drawnItems.addTo(map);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
        console.log('ON MAP CREATED, draw element');
        console.log(e);
         var type = e.layerType,
             layer = e.layer;
     
         if (type === 'marker') {
             // Do marker specific actions
         }
        
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('draw-end', {detail: {type: type}}));
        map.addLayer(layer);
     });

    this.map = map;
  }
```

I was hoping that when an element is being drawn on the map the dispatchEvent method would send me back info about it on the server, as the first 2 console.logs on the map.on() callback are being displayed properly.

I`m pretty much working in the dark here since I have little experience with using polymer elements so any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you seen https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leaflet4vaadin or https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leafletmap-for-vaadin?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add the LeafletDraw plugin on top of this https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leaflet4vaadin

Comment: I guess the problem is that `this` does refer to the context in which the `on` callback is called rather than the component instance. If this is the case, then it can fixed by using an `(e) => { ... }` arrow function instead of the `function(e) { ... }` explicit function.

Comment: You were correct @LeifÅstrand. Thank you. Please write your comment as an answer to accept it.